# Appcelerator Studio accept the SDK license agreements, but all are accepted

Tags: appcelerator

I'm new to appcelerator.  I'm doing a migration of an old app and able to build the ios app, no problem.  I'm trying to get the android version to build.

I get the error "To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager."

I've accepted all of the licenses using
"yes | /Users/edmckee/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates... "

And they are all accepted.

I think I have something configured incorrectly in appcelerator studio, but not sure what to change.

Here's the error I'm receieving

> [ERROR] :  [GRADLE] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. [ERROR] :
> [GRADLE]  [ERROR] :  [GRADLE] * What went wrong: [ERROR] :  [GRADLE]
> Could not determine the dependencies of task
> ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. [ERROR] :  [GRADLE] > Failed to
> install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not
> been accepted. [ERROR] :  [GRADLE]      build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK
> Build-Tools 28.0.3 [ERROR] :  [GRADLE]      platforms;android-29
> Android SDK Platform 29 [ERROR] :  [GRADLE]   To build this project,
> accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components
> using the Android Studio SDK Manager. [ERROR] :  [GRADLE]
> Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation
> to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
> [ERROR] :  [GRADLE]    [ERROR] :  [GRADLE]   Using Android SDK:
> /Users/edmckee/Library/android-sdk-macosx [ERROR] :  [GRADLE]  [ERROR]
> :  [GRADLE] * Try: [ERROR] :  [GRADLE] Run with --stacktrace option to
> get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log
> output. Run with --scan to get full insights. [ERROR] :  [GRADLE]

Comment: I just needed to update the path for the Android SDK.  I matched it to the path that was defined in the Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to update the path for the Android SDK. I matched it to the path that was defined in the Android Studio